# dotnet core docker web api not connecting

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, rider

I am struggling to get my docker container listening on localhost (keep getting site can't be reached). I have followed the official guides on jetbrains and some others I found around the net, but still having no luck.

On my local development I want my web API container and Postgres container to talk to each other, but when live the containers will be communicating with en RDS instance

DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "api/api.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/api"
RUN dotnet build "api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src/api"
RUN dotnet publish "api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll", "--urls", "http://*:8080"]
```

LaunchSettings

```
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:14317",
      "sslPort": 44301
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "wander.api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8081;http://localhost:8080",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Docker debug config
[image: My Docker debug config]

My docker PS
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls share your `docker run` command. I am sure you specified `-p` option.

I am guessing it looks like below:

`docker run <cotainer id> -p 57000:8080`

8080 will be used from within docker container network.

From host machine you'll have access to the API using with `57000`.